# Auto update a buffer opend in a split when it changed?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, save

I'm writing TypeScript and there is a command `npx tsc --watch` that will (over)write to an output file every time the source file is changed. I open one split for each of these files. But when I save the source file the output file didn't get updated. How?

As the following img indicates: I've saved the file on the left, but the file on the right isn't changed/synced. I'm willing to record the entire process if someone really want to help me solve this tricky problem.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. Please check the 'backupcopy' option

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: Could you describe the exact steps to make it work?

Comment: try to explain your problem correctly. The title talks about buffer being updated in a split window, but you are actually writing something like writing a file. So what exactly is your problem? What do you want to achieve? Very unclear to me.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: I just observed that I need to run `:w` twice to reflect the changes I've made to the output file, which is opened in a split in my neovim, which is generated every time the input file, which is also opened in a split in my neovim, is changed.

Comment: That's why I ask another question to ask for the effect that execute `:w` twice when I only run/type it once.

Comment: It's a long shot, but are you looking for something like `autoread`?

Comment: I have given up on solving this question. Now I just press my shortcut twice to achieve this effect. Since some libraries can achieve the so-called auto-save, so this is possible. But (sadly, to me) it seems that many lines are required to achieve this effect.

Comment: @Biggybi: You can say that. But I did try `autoread` (many times), it doesn't work.

Comment: Based on what I've observed, it seems like neovim buffers these update-to-buffer jobs asynchronously (to prevent too many write in a short period, I think).

Comment: Huh? If I `:w` write a file and the output does not appear on the filesystem, that is considered a bug and is really insecure. It may depend on some options however, check `:h 'fsync'` and `:h 'backupcopy'`.

Comment: possibly related vim issue (about filewatchers): https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/9012

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: The scenario you described is for sure insecure, but you misunderstood what I mean. I said "update-to-buffer" jobs: the update of the input file is indeed saved to the file system, while neovim doesn't reflect these changes immediately to the buffer. Instead, (from my observation) I guess that it would defer this change until the next file-save event.

Comment: I doubt this. Why would Neovim defer noticing a change of the buffer on a disk? That doesn't sound plausible.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: I set `vim.opt.swapfile` to `false`. Is `'backupcopy'` a similar idea of it?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Oh, I found the typo in my comment: I should say "to prevent too many __reads__ in a short period" of time. Sorry for being misleading...

Comment: the idea of 'backupcopy' is, to tell Vim how to write a file safely. It usually does create  a backup copy of the current file by renaming the original file. Then it saves the file and copies metadata over. Please check the documentation for that option. BTW: I would never set the swapfile to false. You may lose data!

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: Wow, thanks for your explanation! I had a hard time understanding the documentation... Now I think it's probably related to this option. I set swapfile to false because I never successfully recovered a file using swapfile(s)... (e.g. I opened too many tmux-sessions and I edited the same file differently...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to achieve this in (Neo)Vim. See:

- A pending-many-years(posted  on 2014) issue: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1380
- A promising pending PR: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/20801